# posible : custom flex card

Tags: html, css

```css
.flex-container{
   display: flex;
   /* flex-flow: row; */
   flex-flow: column wrap;
   border: 1px solid black;
   text-align: center;
   height: 200px;
   width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="box box1">1</div>
<div class="box box2">2</div>
<div class="box box3">3</div>
<div class="box box3">3</div>
<div class="box box4">4</div>
<div class="box box4">4</div>
<div class="box box5">5</div>
<div class="box box5">5</div>
<div class="box box6">6</div>
<div class="box box6">6</div>
<div class="box box7">7</div>
<div class="box box7">7</div>
<div class="box box8">8</div>
<div class="box box8">8</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nokin3/L1h7xs0f/1/

In mind:

[image: in mind]
right : in PC, Left for responsive

I try for this and I cant go.

Comment: Please explain what do you want and where is your error.

Comment: I cant do it , dont have error.

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution using `display: grid`.

Achieving the required layout with the below two UI states

[image: UI layouts]

The layout is created by having a major container `grid-container` with three sections `leftSide`, `topSide` and `bottomSide`. Inside the latter, there is a secondary container which is also a grid container with the most important property being:

```css
grid-auto-flow: columns;
```

Finally, we have a media query in which we have a two-column grid.

The complete code is:

```css
   .grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'leftSide topSide'
    'leftSide bottomSide';
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr; /* change proportions here */
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.bottom-container {
  grid-area: bottomSide;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}


@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .bottom-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: initial;
  }
}

.box {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box1 {
  grid-area: leftSide;
}

.box2 {
  grid-area: topSide;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="box box1">1</div>
    <div class="box box2">2</div>
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
      <div class="box">7</div>
      <div class="box">7</div>
      <div class="box">8</div>
      <div class="box">8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: please add a sufficient explanation. `I have a solution..` with just a code snippet is considered "low quality". An anwser should always contain enough expnation to be understood and be reproduciable.

Comment: @tacoshy as the question was not a conceptual problem but a "how do you do this" I have acted accordingly. I will improve the answer tho, it's a work in progress

Comment: thanks a lot, I try to add more code but still error.
I try to more it. @tacoshy,@vanntile